# Intuitive explanation of logloss

Tags: interpretation, intuition, loss-functions

In several kaggle competitions the scoring was based on "logloss".  This relates to classification error.

Here is a [technical answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89887/interpretation-of-logloss-value) but I am looking for an intuitive answer.  I really liked the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance/) about Mahalanobis distance, but PCA is not logloss.

I can use the value that my classification software puts out, but I don't really understand it. Why do we use it instead of true/false positive/negative rates?  Can you help me so that I can explain this to my grandmother or a newbie in the field?

I also like and agree with the quote:

> you do not really understand something unless you can explain it to
>   your grandmother
>   -- Albert Einstein

I tried answering this on my own before posting here.

Links that I did not find intuitive or really helpful include:

- http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-sense-of-logarithmic-loss/
- https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-the-log-loss-function
- https://lingpipe-blog.com/2010/11/02/evaluating-with-probabilistic-truth-log-loss-vs-0-1-loss/
- https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss

These are informative, and accurate.  They are meant for a technical audience.  They do not draw a simple picture, or give a simple and accessible examples.  They are not written for my grandmother.

Comment: you didn't provide a link to your technical answer

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-the-log-loss-function

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani - I did not find those intuitive like the ones for Mahalanobis that I referenced.

Comment: the [entry on the kaggle website](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss) gives a pretty concise explanation of logloss

Comment: Found this link: http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2015/12/making-sense-logarithmic-loss/ . Might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Logloss is the logarithm of the product of all probabilities. Suppose Alice predicted:

- with probability 0.2, John will kill Jack
- with probability 0.001, Mary will marry John
- with probability 0.01, Bill is a murderer.

It turned out that Mary did not marry John, Bill is not a murderer, but John killed Jack. The product of the probabilities, according to Alice, is 0.2*0.999*0.99=0.197802

Bob predicted:

- with probability 0.5, John will kill Jack
- with probability 0.5, Mary will marry John
- with probability 0.5, Bill is a murderer.

The product is 0.5*0.5*0.5=0.125.

Alice is better predictor than Bob.

Comment: why does "product of all probabilities" work?  This sounds like a relative of expectation maximization.

Comment: Do you need a formal proof?  It is in the "technical answer" mentioned by the topicstarter.  Do you need an informal "grandmother" reason why?  You say: suppose this fellow gave correct predictions. What is the probability that everything happen as it really happened? This is the product of probabilities.

Comment: "product of probabilities" isn't "grandma".  log of product of probabilities is sum of log-probabilities, which they use in expectation maximization and call "expectation".  I think it is also encoded in K-L divergence.  ...  I think in grandma-talk you could say" "most likely" = highest overall probability of multiple events.  There are two get "highest": 1) maximize the combined probability or 2) minimize the negative combined probability.  Most machine learning likes "gradient descent" or minimizing badness.  Log-loss is the negative probability scaled by sample size, and it gets minimized.

Comment: Here [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113301/multi-class-logarithmic-loss-function-per-class) they say "exp(-loss) is average probability of correct prediction."

Comment: I liked the Bishop ref [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html).  It is equation 4.108 and is the cross-entropy error function.